# if $2a_n+b_n$ and $a_n+3b_n$, both converge to a finite limit, then do $a_n,b_n$ also converge to a final limit?

Tags: calculus

What I did: if if $lim_{n\to \infty}2a_n+b_n=L_1$ and $lim_{n\to \infty}a_n+3b_n=L_2$. 
Then $lim_{n\to \infty}(2a_n+b_n-2(a_n+3b_n))=L_1-2L_2=lim_{n\to\infty}(-2b_n)$. 
But here I'm wondering, I know that If I know that $c_n$,$d_n$, converge then $lim_{n\to\infty}c_n*d_n$ converges. 
Here I know that $lim(-2)=-2$, but I don't know that $lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ converges, it's what I'm trying to prove, so my question is: 
 Is it valid to say that if $lim_{n\to\infty}(-2b_n)=L_1-2L_2$, then $lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=\frac {L_1-2L_2}{-2}$?

Comment: Just write $b_n=-2b_n/(-2)$ and apply quotient rule of limits.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

$$a_n = \frac{1}{5}\left[3(2a_n+b_n)-(a_n+3b_n)\right]$$
$$b_n=-\frac{1}{5}\left[(2a_n+b_n)-2(a_n+3b_n)\right]$$

Comment: Appreciate the hint! so in general it wasn't valid to do what I asked? I need both of the sequences to be convergent in the product?

Comment: Yes, but the point here is that you have to *deduce* that $a_n$ and $b_n$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $c_n$ converges to $L$ then $Ac_n$ converges to $AL$ for any constant $A$

If $A=0$ this is trivial, and otherwise I can choose $N$ so that with $n\gt N$ we have $|c_n-L|\lt \frac {\epsilon}{|A|}$ (using the freedom I have to beat any small number I choose) and $|Ac_n-AL|\lt \epsilon$.

You are right to ask questions about this - generally limits work when you add and multiply (you should see how much you can prove yourself), but you have to be very careful about dividing by zero (in cases where you are dividing by $a_n$ and $a_n$ has a non-zero limit, it is prudent to choose $n$ large enough that you can bound $a_n$ away from zero).